# Why the SWAP listed in the detail list of the TOP command is greater than in the summary?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, ubuntu, top-command

The TOP command results:

```
Mem:   3991840k total,  1496328k used,  2495512k free,   156752k buffers  
**Swap**:  3905528k total,     **3980k** used,  3901548k free,   447860k cached  

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  **SWAP** COMMAND  
28250 www-data  20   0  430m 210m  21m R   63  5.4   0:07.29 **219m** apache2  
28266 www-data  20   0  256m  40m  21m S   30  1.0   0:01.94 **216m** apache2  
28206 www-data  20   0  260m  44m  21m S   27  1.1   0:10.27 **215m** apache2  
28259 www-data  20   0  256m  40m  21m S   26  1.0   0:02.21 **216m** apache2
```

The details list shows a group of apache2 processes are using SWAP memory about 210m+ each, but the summary reports only 3980k is used. The total SWAP memory in the detail list is much greater than in the summary. Do the two `swap` refer the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoted from http://www.linuxforums.org/articles/using-top-more-efficiently_89.html :

> VIRT=RES+SWAP
>
> As explained previously, VIRT includes anything inside task's
> address space, no matter it is in RAM,
> swapped out or still not loaded from
> disk. While RES represents total RAM
> consumed by this task. So, SWAP here
> means it represents the total amount
> of data being swapped out OR still not
> loaded from disk. Don't be fooled by
> the name, it doesn't just represent
> the swapped out data.